# vSphere SDK how to delete VirtualMachine in JAVA

Tags: java, vmware, vsphere

I'm struggeling to find a way of deleting VirtualMachine by using vSphere SDK JAVA API, but seems like nothing works. As far as i know, i need to get an instance of VirtualMachine ManagedObject and call Destroy_Task() , but until now I'm only able to get ManagedObjectReference of virtual machine by using PropertyCollector which is not helpful for this specific task.

I cannot find any example on the internet that would show how to do it, hope someone here can help me.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK I manage to solve it..SO ManagedObject is a server side object, on the client side we can only get access to a ManageObjectReference,

To execute methods of ManagedObject we need to call them trough VimPortType vimPort. SO steps for deleting Virtual Machine trough API are

1. We get ManagedObjectReference of particular Virtual Machine
2. Call vimPort(mor) where mor in ManagedObjectReference from step 1.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to perform an operation on VMware instances using java api.

1. Get Service Instance
2. Get root folder from service instance
3. Search for Virtual Machine using vmname in root folder
4. Perform the operation

`Folder rootFolder = serviceInstance.getRootFolder();
InventoryNavigator inventoryNavigator = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder);
vm = (VirtualMachine) inventoryNavigator.searchManagedEntity(VirtualMachine.class.getSimpleName(), vmName);
Task task = vm.powerOffVM_Task();
task.waitForTask();
Task task1 = vm.destroy_Task();`

As of now, I have worked on java api of almost all the clouds. But VMware's api is the best one to work on. You just have to dive deep into it.